# Javascript Array Specific Order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of js object

```
const name = 'Levi'
var data = [ 
{ firstname: 'Levi', food: 'apple'     },
{ firstname: 'Eren', food: 'orange'   },
{ firstname: 'Levi', food: 'grapes' },
{ firstname: 'Miks', food: 'banana' }
];
```

How can I sort the firstname and prioritized (Levi) as on top.

Expected Output:

```
[{firstname: Levi, food: apple},
{ firstname: Levi, food: grapes },
{ firstname: Eren, food: orange   },
{ firstname: Miks, food: banana}]
```

I used this code

```
this.data.sort((a, b) => (a.firstname > name) ? 1 : ((name> a.firstname) ? -1 : 0));
```

Comment: Step 1: implement sorting you want but without prioritisation. When you have it - update the question.

Comment: `this.data.sort((a, b) => (a.firstname === name) ? -1 : (b.firstname === name) ? 1 : a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname));`

Answer (score 1):

The first check both `a` and `b` firstname are `name` or not, if true, do nothing.

Next, check `a` firstname or `b` firstname is `name`, if true, find who has firstname is `name`, and swap `a` and `b` or not.

Finally, check with alphabetical order rule.

```
const name = 'Levi'
var data = [
  { firstname: 'Levi', food: 'apple' },
  { firstname: 'Eren', food: 'orange' },
  { firstname: 'Levi', food: 'grapes' },
  { firstname: 'Miks', food: 'banana' },
  { firstname: 'AMiks', food: 'mango' }
];

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.firstname === name && b.firstname === name) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (a.firstname === name || b.firstname === name) {
    return a.firstname === name ? -1 : 1;
  }
  return a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname);
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Output:

```
[ { firstname: 'Levi', food: 'apple' },
  { firstname: 'Levi', food: 'grapes' },
  { firstname: 'AMiks', food: 'banana' },
  { firstname: 'Eren', food: 'orange' },
  { firstname: 'Miks', food: 'banana' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If a and b firstnames are equal to name, then sort on their food.
If a firstname is name, then prioritize.

```js
const name = "Levi";
var data = [
  { firstname: "Levi", food: "apple" },
  { firstname: "Eren", food: "orange" },
  { firstname: "Levi", food: "grapes" },
  { firstname: "Miks", food: "banana" }
];

const sortAsc = (a, b) => {
  if (b > a) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
};

data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.firstname === name && b.firstname === name) {
    return sortAsc(a.food, b.food);;
  }
  if (a.firstname === name) {
    return -1;
  }
});


console.log(data);
```